# How to run one command on several cores

Tags: bash, parallelism, multithreading

I have a command which I want to run on all free cores to speed up the execution time. Specifically I am running the Pitman-Yor Adaptor-Grammar Sampler software I downloaded from [here](http://web.science.mq.edu.au/%7Emjohnson/code/py-cfg-2013-09-23.tgz)

```
./py-cfg/py-cfg-mp -r 0 -d 10 -x 10 -D -E  -e 1 -f 1 -g 10 -h 0.1 -w 1 -T 1 -m 0 -n 500 -G x.tgt y.tgt < z.tgt
```

I tried adding `parallel -j "$(nproc)"` before the command as specified [in this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364224/run-command-on-multiple-threads)

but it is generating the following error:

```
Error in ./py-cfg/py-cfg-mp, argc = 29, optind = 27
```

Comment: But you're not going to show us the actual command you ran to get this error?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is: It depends.

You can run the same program with different input in parallel with GNU Parallel:

```
parallel gzip ::: *.txt
```

this will run `gzip` on every `.txt`-file in the current dir.

`gzip` is single threaded, so each instance only uses a single CPU core.

This is not that complex.

If, however, you wanted to parallelize `gzip` so it used multiple cores to compress a single (big) `.txt`-file, the task is much more complex. In practice you would use a different program (such as `pigz`) that is build for that.

In other words: You cannot automatically make `gzip` multithreaded.

I do not know Pitman-Yor Adaptor-Grammar Sampler. If it like `gzip` is single-threaded, you can run multiple instances on different input (and GNU Parallel can help you do that). But you cannot automatically convert the Sampler to run on multiple cores given a single input.

If this is not clear, try making a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Yes. As Theodore von Kármán put it, "Everyone knows it takes a woman nine months to have a baby. But you Americans think if you get nine women pregnant, you can have a baby in a month." In order to effectively parallelize a task, 1) it must be parallelizable (unlike gzip and pregnancy), and 2) you need to understand *how* the overall task can be broken into smaller tasks that can be performed in parallel.